# Split an array based on whether the elements occur in another array or not

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

In this situation, I have two arrays

```
oldIDs = [1, 2]
newIDs = [2, 3, 4]
```

**question:** 
how to split "newIDs" into [[2], [3,4]] ?

**explanation:** 
2 is an old id (It is existed in `oldIDs`) 
3 & 4 are new ids (which are not existed in `oldIDs`)

---

Other examples:

```
oldIDs = [1]
newIDs = [1, 2]
// the result should be [[1], [2]]

oldIDs = [1, 3, 5]
newIDs = [3, 4, 7, 8]
// the result should be [[3], [4, 7, 8]]

oldIDs = [1, 2, 4] 
newIDs = [2, 3, 4]
// the result should be [[2, 4], [3]]
```

This is what I'm doing with Go.

```
func splitIDs(oldIDs []int64, newIDs []int64) (arr1 []int64, arr2 []int64) {
    for _, newID := range newIDs {
        if contains(oldIDs, newID) {
            arr1 = append(arr1, newID)
        }
    if !contains(oldIDs, newID) {
            arr2 = append(arr2, newID)
        }
    }
    return
}

func contains(a []int64, x int64) bool {
    for _, n := range a {
        if x == n {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

This can also be divided into two arrays, not necessarily two dimensional array.

I really appreciate someone who can solve my problem or improve my solution.

Comment: is it guaranteed that there will be only one element, common in both the arrays.?

Comment: I understand you want to separate the IDs in newIDs into does that occur in oldIDs and does that do not?

Comment: are the 2 lists sorted? if so you can solve this with 2 pointers: one for each list

Comment: Yes @Luka that's correct!

Comment: Not always in sequence @NirF

Comment: correction: I mean at least there is one number in common @Liju

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a program in python.
This first read through old id, creates a dictionary out of it.
and read through the new ids looking for common number, to split.

```py
oldIDs = [1, 2, 4]
newIDs = [2, 3, 4]
def split(oldIDs,newIDs):
    o_dict={}
    present=[]
    not_present=[]
    for i in oldIDs:
        o_dict[i]=True
    for i,num in enumerate(newIDs):
        if num in o_dict: # O(1)
            present.append(num)
        else:
            not_present.append(num)
    return [present,not_present]
print(split(oldIDs,newIDs))
```

Comment: Thank you @Liju, I appreciate it, but let me learn you code first

Comment: I can't solve with this input `oldIDs = [1, 2, 4] newIDs = [2, 3, 4]` your code resulting `[[2], [3, 4]]`, the result should be `[[2 4] [3]]`

Comment: But in the question comments, you confirmed, there will be only one number in common..!! here there are 2 common numbers 2 and 4.

Comment: oh my bad, sorry. I mean at least there is one number in common

Comment: @Rza I've updated the program above.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the arrays intersection and the arrays difference and combine them into one array as follows:

```js
const oldIDs = [1, 3, 5]
const newIDs = [3, 4, 7, 8]

const splitArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const result = []
  //Getting the arrays intersection
  result[0] = arr2.filter((item) => {
    return arr1.includes(item)
  })
  //Getting the arrays difference
  result[1] = arr2.filter((item) => {
    return !arr1.includes(item)
  })
  return result
}

console.log(splitArray(oldIDs, newIDs))
```

Comment: Thank you @Seif Alaa, I appreciate it, but let me understand you code first

Comment: Most welcome, just ask me if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is a library (not surprisingly) for this same purpose. It is [`split_into`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_into) available in [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

All you need to do is:

```py
res = list(more_itertools.split_into(newIDs, oldIDs + [None]
           * (len(newIDs) - len(oldIDs))))

res = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, res))
```

---

Otherwise if you want to write your own loop ( which I prefer ):

```py
def split_newIDs(oldIDs, newIDs):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    res = []
    while i < len(newIDs):
        res.extend([newIDs[i:i + oldIDs[j]]])
        i += oldIDs[j]
        if j < len(oldIDs) - 1:
            j += 1
    return res


print split_newIDs(oldIDs, newIDs)
```

What is this doing is, keep checking if you have seen all elements in newIDs but also keeping a check on the index in your oldIDs so that you keep using the oldIDs if you fall short.

You can use [this](https://replit.com/@somdude/WiryLeafySpreadsheet#main.py) to run the code.

Comment: Thank you @SomeDude, I appreciate it, but let me understand you code first